# Can anyone help to properly convert milliseconds to (y/m/d) in C# with TimeSpan?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to date. This is my code:

the original ms value is = 1507074136994;
and expected output is 2017/10/03;

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
string strFromNow=DateTime.Now.Add(ts).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

value of strFromNow return => 2065-08-02 :c

Comment: You need to know the epoch to add to.  Likely it's January 1st 1970.

Comment: Add milliseconds to what date? Your question is incomplete. You are adding them to `Now`, if that is not what you want you have to tell us what you actually want.

Comment: What is your input and expected output? What is the value of `ms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to calculate this:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01); // Unix Epoch

DateTime result = epoch.AddMilliseconds(1507074136994);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 03/10/2017 23:42:16 (UK format)
```

Comment: The OP does not state how the number of miliseconds was derived. As the question is marked C#, the Unix epoch is unlikely to be the correct one.

Comment: @PhilipSmith The OP states the input number and the expected output, and a trivial test will show that it matches the Unix Epoch. It's also not unusual for a C# program to have to deal with Unix date/time values - even more so now that .Net Core is supported on Linux!

Comment: Information you omitted from your answer.

Comment: @PhilipSmith How so? I state that he needs to use the Unix epoch, and my sample code contains the input value (`1507074136994`) and a comment shows the output: `// 03/10/2017 23:42:16 (UK format)`. I even linked the wiki page on the Unix Epoch,  What should I add to that?

Comment: Exactly, you told the OP that he should conform to Unix standards. Despite the fact that all the evidence indicates a Windows user. You did not "state" that you had determined the Epoch. Your answer comes across as a Unix pedant Windows bashing. I half expected an edit stating that the Windows time libraries were broken, because they do not conform to Unix standards.

Comment: @PhilipSmith *Your answer comes across as a Unix pedant Windows bashing* My reply is purely factual, devoid of any subtext. I'm rather suprised that you would think otherwise. Are you really sure you're not reading too much into my reply? I've never used Unix, and almost all of my posts on Stackoverlow relate to C# on Windows... Ah well.